# Can we add Folder content type to Document set?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, document-set

we  want to next Folders in Document Sets. Is this possible?

Comment: Yes it is possible..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible, through code. However, [putting folders inside Document Sets is unsupported by Microsoft](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff603637%28v=office.14%29.aspx), and can lead to strange results.  Believe me, I have tried.  One of the things I have noticed is that a folder inside a Document Set will block the metadata inheritance from the shared fields of the Document Set.  Documents inside the sub-folder will inherit the *fields* that are shared, but they will always remain empty, they will not inherit the *values* of the shared fields.

Also, I do not know whether or not you can add a Folder content type as an allowed content type of a Document Set.  I do know that the "New Folder" ribbon button is disabled when viewing a Document Set.

Answer (score 1):

Come again? I don't necessarily understand the question, but "Document Set" is a content type that inherits from "Folder". If you'd like to extend this, you can extend the Document Set content type, rather than extend the "Folder" content type.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to configure a Folder Content Types - these can be used as folders within your document set.  I've posted a similar question and have an answer to it - [it's here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/232500/how-to-set-content-types-per-folder-within-a-document-set).  I'm using SP 2013 by the way.

'Folder level views' can be configured by using this method.  Therefore you can have multiple content types in a Document Library and have a folder/content type specific view configured for them.  I've not tried with meta-data, but this is possible to do with columns.

For further info, see [Cameron Dwyer's blog post](https://camerondwyer.wordpress.com/2014/01/06/harness-sharepoint-default-views-at-different-navigation-hierarchy-levels-to-build-more-appealing-solutions/#customfolder).