# How to set content-types per folder within a Document Set

Tags: 2013, content-type, document-set

I've searched through lots of similar questions, but surprisingly have not found one that matches up with what I am doing.

I am using Document Sets for a HR document library; each Doc Set automatically creates 5 folders.

Each folder will use different content types.

I will assign custom templates to be used for some of the content types, things like letter templates with the company logo.

Here is an example of a Document Set with the 5 folders.

[image: Doc Set screen shot showing 5 folders]

I would like to make the 'Contracts' content type available only within the **2 - Contracts, T_Cs, Employee Benefits** folder.  At present it is only possible to do New Document>`Contracts` content type at the Document Library level (see screen shot below):

[image: Available content types]

If I try to add New Document>`Contracts` with an Employee Document Set e.g. Joe Bloggs/**2 - Contracts, T_Cs, Employee Benefits**>New Document, I can not choose the `Contracts` content type:

[image: No Contracts content type available]

I'd like to make `Contracts` available at the folder level and unavailable at the Document Library Level as only new Document Sets should be set up there.

**Update - additional picture referenced in comments**

[image: List Content Type Picture]

Referenced Links:

[Link](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/175476/define-content-types-available-in-a-document-set), [Link](https://sharepointmaven.com/implement-document-management-system-sharepoint/), [Link](https://sharepointmaven.com/document-sets-hidden-gem-sharepoint/), [Link](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-and-configure-a-new-Document-Set-content-type-9db6d6dc-c23a-4dcd-a359-3e4bbbc47fc1)

Comment: As far as I know, content types are added to libraries only, not folders.

Comment: I'll add an additional screen shot of what I found in Library Settings>Content Types (I select my Employee content type)>List Content Type>Document Set Settings>Allowed Content Types.  From this menu it appears that you can define the content types to be used **within** the  document set.

Comment: I haven't tried this, but I'd guess using content organizer (with a Drop Off Library obviously) this should be possible. Sure it's a bit away from your initial approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cameron Dwyer's excellent [blog post](https://camerondwyer.wordpress.com/2014/01/06/harness-sharepoint-default-views-at-different-navigation-hierarchy-levels-to-build-more-appealing-solutions/#customfolder) had the answer.  I had not been using folder content types, which are used in this Sharepoint configuration.  This is why I had been unable to configure individual folder-level views (for my purposes each folder = an individual content type).

The solution involved creating multiple Folder Content Types and adding those CTs to the Document Library.

Here is what I was stuck on - I made a note of it for myself, but thought I'd share a screenshot of it for other peoples benefit in case they hit the same problem.

[image: Folder content type views]

For further reading, [Cameron also posted an answer](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/43686/need-a-different-views-for-folders-files-in-document-library) to a question on SP SE.