# Automated creating a folder structure based on another list

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, document-library

I have the following requirements to be implemented inside SharePoint online:-

1. We have custom list named "Folder Structure Template", with 10 check-boxes, as follows:-

   - Cost structure checkbox.
   - Asset Structure checkbox.
   - and so on
2. Based on the above check-boxes, the folder structure will be created. So if the user selects the "Cost Structure" checkbox and creates a new item, a sub-folder named "Costing" will be created and so on. If the user selects 2 check-boxes then 2 sub-folders will be created..
3. Each sub-folder will be linked to a couple of metadata and the documents inside the folders should inherit the metadata

So I am not sure if any of the available SharePoint tools support this type of implementation; Flow, SharePoint workflow, or document sets? or do I need to write some code inside a console application or inside a remote event receiver to implement this?

---

**EDIT**
Based on @Drek comment, I will add this extra info. We want to build a folder structure for our company so users can create a new item inside a custom list >> inside the create form the user can chose from 10 check-boxes named (Cost, Asset, Info, external parties, meetings, service manual, contacts, back-up plan, disaster recovery, IT). 
Now lets say a user creates a new item inside the custom list and the user selects these 4 check-boxes:-
1. IT.
2. Meeting.
3. Cost.
4. Asset.

The system should then automatically create a new main folder with the custom list item ID + 4 sub-folders inside a document library; named IT, Meeting, Cost & Asset.

Also each folder will be linked to managed metadata columns.

Comment: It's not really clear to me what you're trying to do here. Try describing your problem more as a business problem than a half-completed technical implementation. You might get some better ideas that way.

Comment: @DerekGusoff thanks for the comment, this is my first question, i edit it with more details.

Comment: where do the folders get created?

Comment: @DerekGusoff inside a document library. so i have a custom list to define the checkboxes and a document library which will contain the folders

Comment: So is each item in the list a new library with the indicated folder structure? How do the libraries get created?

Comment: @DerekGusoff it is the same library with which contain root folder = the list item ID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use remove event receiver to do the work. both Flow and Workflow will have limitation in your case.

Answer (score 1):

I've faced a similar scenario myself; I used [document sets](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/introduction-to-document-sets-3dbcd93e-0bed-46b7-b1ba-b31de2bcd234) ([yet more info here](https://sharepointmaven.com/document-sets-hidden-gem-sharepoint/)) to create a document set and a handful of sub-folders.  It sounds rather similar to what you are doing.

In a nutshell: editing a List item then triggers a workflow to create a document set (and sub-folders) in a Document Library.

Here's [my post](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/232500/how-to-set-content-types-per-folder-within-a-document-set) which makes use of Cameron Dwyer's excellent [blog post](https://camerondwyer.wordpress.com/2014/01/06/harness-sharepoint-default-views-at-different-navigation-hierarchy-levels-to-build-more-appealing-solutions/#customfolder).

If you're really new to Sharepoint you might find this a bit complex, but for me it proved to be a massive time saver once it was set up, no need to manually create all the folders and rename them once this was up and running.

For your point #3 regarding meta-data - I guess you could use the `Set` command in the workflow to set a meta-data field to the desired value based on the folder name.